# Case Class in scala for nested JSON

Tags: scala, spray-json

**SCALA**

My nested JSON appeared as given below.

```
{"event":"movie","on":"bollywood","reldate":"2019-06-01T18:20:00.560Z","data":{"id":"4965-81dc-4ef","location":{"ratioin":52.48077,"ratioout":13.42499,"reldate":"2019-06-01T18:20:00.560Z"}},"mov_id":"org-id"}
```

I have written a case class as given below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.json._
import spark.implicits._


case class Activity(
    event: string,
    on :string,
    reldate :string,
    data: array[1],
    location: array[2],
    mov: string,
)
```

but this is throwing error.

can someone please help me.

Comment: The scala keywords for case class are case-sensitive, sho it should be `case class`

Comment: Please add a tag for the library you're using for deserializing JSON and also provide code you're using to do deserialization.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik: i have added the library by editing the question

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik: please help me if i am missing or my approach is wrong

Comment: @HaraldGliebe: please help me if i am missing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create nested classes that match the nested JSON, something like this:

```
case class Activity(
  event: String,
  on: String,
  reldate: String,
  data: ActivityData,
  mov_id: String,
)

case class ActivityData(
  id: String,
  location: ActivityLocation
)

case class ActivityLocation(
  ratioin: Double,
  ratiouut: Double,
  reldate: String
)
```